# Resuming a job with 'r' in ZSH

Tags: zsh, documentation, job-control

I run Vim in zsh. And I often need to check something else in the terminal. So I just quickly suspend the editor by pressing **Ctrl+Z** and then type **fg** to get back.

Today, by chance, I noticed that the suspended job can be resumed by typing just **r**. I guess it stands for *resume*. However, this command works only immediately after suspending the job. If I run any shell command I have to use **fg**.

Is this feature documented somewhere? Or is it a hidden gem? I couldn't find.

(ZSH 5.1.1 on Fedora Linux.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the help for it (`run-help r`), you’ll see it listed at the bottom of the help for `fc`. It is quoted as:

> Same as fc -e -

But you won’t find the `-e` option directly described there. One can expect that it refers to the editor. A later reference to *ename* states:

> If ename  is  `-', no editor is invoked.  When editing is complete, the edited command is executed.

Since no editor is invoked, it simply **r**epeats the last command. So I will take `r` to mean “Repeat”.

I don’t think your backgrounded job is actually *resuming*. When I tried your use case, an identical job was created.

I was flummoxed at one point as to why I couldn’t invoke an `r` command I knew had installed via the `littler` package. It was masked by the unintuitive Zsh command that I was unaware of. I find any single-character command (e.g., `r`) to be prime real estate, and I don’t use Zsh’s version of it. So I kill it off in my `~/.zshrc` with:

```
disable r
```

Comment: Thank you. Obviously 'r' repeated my previous 'fg' invocation. Mystery resolved.